# キーボードショートカットでタブのナビゲーションができない

Tags: バグ, 完了

英語版SOで、キーボードショートカットを有効にしてプロフィールページで<kbd>n</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>キーを押すと、ページ内のタブにジャンプすることができます（左図）。日本語版ではこのショートカットキーが使えません（右図）。

[image: 英語版のタブナビゲーション] [image: 日本語版のタブナビゲーション]

### 期待する動作

英語版と同じショートカットキーでタブにジャンプできることを期待します。

日本語のアプリケーションでも、英語のアプリケーションをローカライズしたものでも、キーボードショートカットはASCII文字（または修飾キーとASCII文字）とアクションを対応付けるのが一般的かと思います。

たとえばGmailはインターフェースの言語を英語にしても日本語にしても同じキーマップです:

[image: gmail-en] [image: gmail-ja]

ショートカットキーを想像しやすくするために日本語版では日本語のタブ名に呼応したショートカットにする、という仕様も考えられます（「回答」タブは<kbd>k</kbd>でアクセスする、など）。しかし、キーボードショートカットは、各キーを指に覚えさせることで半自動的に操作できることが主眼の機能なので、表示言語に関わらず同じショートカットで操作できることの方が、初期の学習コストの低減効果を上回るメリットがあると思います。（違う言語のサイトを行き来するユーザーが一定数いることを前提としています。）

### ショートカットが使えない直接的な原因

タブ名からショートカットキーを生成する関数の中で、キーの候補としてアルファベットのみを取り出しているからのようです。タブ名が日本語だと、キーの候補がなくなってしまいます。

```
i.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, "").toUpperCase()
```

プロフィールページに限らず、タグ情報ページの "order questions by..." ショートカットなどでも同じ問題があります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixes for the keyboard shortcuts plugin are rolling out in the next build (rev `2015.3.11.2379`).